# Inline style in reactjs - multiple values style properties

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles

I have a circle component that can receive a width value. This prop is optional. If the component doesn't receive any width value it uses the default defined in the class. If the component receives a value it is setted as inline style for width, height and line-height.

Also only should set if the value is bigger than 50.

I have this:

```
function Circle(props: ICircleProps) {
    return (
        <div className={`defaultClassName
              style={{width: props.width && props.width > 50 ? props.width : '',
                height: props.width && props.width > 50 ? props.width : '',
                lineHeight: props.width && props.width > 50 ? props.width+'px' : ''}}
        >Circle
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am wondering if this is the correct way or there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

you can render style keys only if the conditions passed. it is better to not render empty string as the values since it is not provided.

```js
function Circle(props: ICircleProps) {
const {width} = props
const style = {
  ...(width>50 && {width:width}),
  ...(width>50 && {height:width}),
  ...(width>50 && {lineHeight:width+'px'}),
}
    return (
        <div className={`defaultClassName`} style={style}>Circle
        </div>
    )
}
```